# How to fit data to Clayton copula and find the p-value for K-S GOF test in R?

Tags: r, modeling

I'm trying to fit a bivariate data, [data1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TCf5DuMTwEjt-nCvXdQ1I9YWVTzHaB8w/view?usp=sharing) to Clayton copula and do the K-S GOF test to find the p-value. I'm referring to this [example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/how-to-determine-which-distribution-fits-my-data-best). Here is my code.

```
f1 <- summary(fitCopula(claytonCopula(dim = 2),data1, method="ml",start=1.5)) #fit the data to copula

n.sims <- 1e3

stats <- replicate(n.sims,{
  r <- rCopula(n=length(data1),
               claytonCopula(param = f1$coefficients[1,1],dim = 2))
  estfit.clayton <- fitCopula(claytonCopula(),r, method="ml", start=1.5)
  r2 <- summary(estfit.clayton)
  as.numeric(ks.test(r,"pCopula",
                     claytonCopula(param = r2$coefficients[1,1],dim = 2))$statistic)
}) 

plot(ecdf(stats), las = 1, main = "KS-test statistic simulation (CDF)", col = "darkorange", lwd = 1.7)
grid()

fit <- oldlogspline(stats)

1-poldlogspline(ks.test(data1,"pCopula",
                     claytonCopula(param = f1$coefficients[1,1],dim = 2))$statistic
             ,fit) #to find K-S p-value
```

The p-value that I got is `0.9999926`. Then I also use ecdf to get the K-S p-value but I didn't get the same or close p-value, `0.007`. I tried to run the example and get a close p-value.

```
ecdf(stats)(ks.test(data1, "pCopula",
                    claytonCopula(param = f1$coefficients[1,1],dim = 2))) #K-S p-value
```

My question is: Why didn't I get the same or close p-value and can I use this method for my problem?